# using html forms in jsp file

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I have a very simple question....I have multiple jsp files like `login.jsp` , `Registration.jsp` , `forgetpassword.jsp` each having their owm `forms` to take `input` from user. So, my question is.....Is it OK to have these many files or should I include all my html forms in a `single file` like `user_auth.jsp` and use javascript`[Which i have no idea how to do]` to display them individually......

All these files process the inputs taken by user against mysql database. I am using Struts 1.3.8 framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that anybody would argue that you should have all of those forms in a single file. Most web pages will have some sort of form on them, it's just how it goes. I would stick with your current model.

Comment: so according to u my current model that is multiple jsp files is OK....but i read somewhere it is a bad practice to have so many files...it should be all forms in one jsp page.

Comment: I don't know where you read that, but if you create a single file that has all of the forms it becomes a JavaScript nightmare. You may want to put each form in its own `.jsp` file, because that would help you reuse them, but you would never want to put all of those forms in the same file.